# async return to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my code i have an async function that retuns an object i have to work with it outside the function but i dont really know how to assign it to a variable, I know this post might be a duplicate but i read the others and tried and it doesn't work.

```
async function name(url) {
//function

return {
    item1:{ ....},
    item2:{....}
} 
}

let p = name(url); 
console.log(p);
```

it returns in the console:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

but it doesn't log the output

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are async. You need to get the result using

1. A callback, specified to the `then` method of the promise.

```js
name(url).then(p => console.log(p))
```

2. Or use an async context and use the `await` keyword:

```js
(async(){

let p = await name(url);
console.log(p);

})();
```